# Working in Landscape Orientation to make a To-Do List

Tags: sectioning, formatting, lists, positioning

I'm essentially trying to re-create the following (Which may have been created in Microsoft Word) with LaTeX. I have figured out how to get into landscape orientation but it goes down onto a new page instead of moving rightways across the file to fill in the empty space.

I'm fairly sure I need to tweak both the margins and the size of the text to ensure everything fits correctly but I'm trying to tackle this one problem at a time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\section*{Monday}

\subsection*{Work}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}

\section*{Tuesday}

\subsection*{Work}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Desired document.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `multicol` package:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\columnsep}{35pt}

\begin{multicols}{4}

\small

\section*{Monday}

\subsection*{Work}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\section*{Friday}

\subsection*{Work}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\section*{Tuesday}

\subsection*{Work}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\section*{Saturday}

\subsection*{Work}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\section*{Wednesday}

\subsection*{Work}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\section*{Sunday}

\subsection*{Work}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\section*{Thursday}

\subsection*{Work}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\section*{Week}

\hrulefill

\vspace*{4pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{4pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{4pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{4pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{4pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{4pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{4pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{4pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{4pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{4pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{4pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{4pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{4pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\end{multicols}   

\end{document}
```

Another version with sans serif font

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\subsection}
  {\large\bfseries}
  {\uppercase}
  {}
  {}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\columnsep}{35pt}

\begin{multicols}{4}

\small

\section*{Monday}

\subsection*{Work}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\section*{Friday}

\subsection*{Work}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\section*{Tuesday}

\subsection*{Work}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\section*{Saturday}

\subsection*{Work}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\section*{Wednesday}

\subsection*{Work}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\section*{Sunday}

\subsection*{Work}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\section*{Thursday}

\subsection*{Work}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\vspace*{-15pt}\hrulefill
\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}

\section*{Week}

\hrulefill

\vspace*{3.5pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{3.5pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{3.5pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{3.5pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{3.5pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{3.5pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{3.5pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{3.5pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{3.5pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{3.5pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{3.5pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{3.5pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\vspace*{3.5pt}\noindent\hrulefill

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks for the answer; I'm not too good at LaTex yet, and I appreciate the time.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `lscape` package , the landscape mode can be achieved. You will have to use the environment `\begin{landscape}` and `\end{landscape}`. Secondly, to put the appropriate things on a single page or the number of pages as per requirement you have you use the `multicols`package and the multicols `environment` having an argument of the number of columns you require in the page. Here is the code as per the requirement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty} 

\sectionfont{\normalfont\sffamily\large\underline\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\section*{Monday}

\subsection*{Work}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \i
  \item 
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}
\columnbreak
\section*{Tuesday}

\subsection*{Work}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}
\columnbreak
\section*{Wednesday}

\subsection*{Work}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \i
  \item 
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}
\columnbreak
\section*{Thursday}

\subsection*{Work}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Projects}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \i
  \item 
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Personal}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The output that was generated :

[image]

Comment: I've posted on the above response; thanks for giving me a solution to the problem! Can't figure out how to close the question.. I'm going to play around with all of the packages suggested to try and get a grip on their use.

Comment: Happy to help. Remember that the best way to say thank you over here is to accept (and upvote) the answer. See how here: How do you accept an answer?